# How to set line breaking of anonymous method in Resharper?

Tags: c#, resharper

Example before code cleanup:

```
Action a = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

After cleanup by Resharper:

```
Action a = () => { Console.WriteLine(); }
```

But I prefer the first style, how to set Resharper to prevent it wrap the method body in the same line?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

*Place simple anonymous method on single line*

[image: Screenshot]